# "FATAL: No nodes returned from search!" while searching or accessing node using SSH

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am using EC2 for creating instances.

When I run `knife node list`, I can see all nodes

```
NodeA,
NodeB,
NodeC
```

When I try to search `NodeC`, it gives me an error message

```
FATAL: No nodes returned from search!
```

I am getting same error when I try to access same node `NodeC` using SSH.

```
$ knife search node name:NodeC
FATAL: No nodes returned from search!
```

But when I run `knife node list`, I can see `NodeC` in the list.

Even when I run `knife search node:`, it shows all nodes except `NodeC`

Can anyone suggest solution on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has NodeC completed a successful run of `chef-client`?  An up-to-date set of attributes is not uploaded to the Chef server if this is not the case which would explain why you are not seeing anything from `knife-search`.

Comment: No couldn't run chef-client, because whenever I tried to run Chef-client, it gave me same error **"FATAL: No nodes returned from search!"**.. I had created EC2 instances and bootstrapping, after that I was trying to access that node using SSH. Node/Instances created earlier are working fine.

Comment: Try running modifying the node's run list to be empty and then doing a run of `chef-client` to get some basic attributes onto the Chef server.  That should allow the search to work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too. `knife node list` would return the server name but trying to run knife commands using the server name would error out with `FATAL: No nodes returned from search!`. I don't know exactly what is causing the problem but it seems like something hasn't fully registered on the chef server and needs a little more time. I haven't seen this behavior until recently. Maybe something changed in Chef 11. Anyhow what I ended up doing was putting my first `knife ssh` command in my build script inside a while loop. It just keeps trying until the command is successful. Sometimes it works on the first try and other times I have seen it take three attempts. Probably should add a counter so it quits after some number of attempts. Here is the bash code I'm using:

```sh
    echo "Waiting until the knife utility can run apt-get successfully on the remote server."
    while true
    do
        knife ssh "name:${SERVERNAME}" "sudo apt-get update" -i sshkey.pem -x ubuntu --yes
        CMDSTATUS=$?
        echo STATUS: $CMDSTATUS
        if [ $CMDSTATUS -eq 0 ]
        then
           echo "knife ssh command was successful. Continuing"
           break
        fi
        echo "knife ssh command failed. Will try again."
        echo "Sleeping 15 seconds..."
        sleep 15
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

similar error message happened to me when running chef-client using winrm:
`knife winrm ADDRESS chef-client --manual-list --winrm-user USER --winrm-password 'PASSWORD'`
the problem was (probably me) that I've bootstrapped the server twice and updated some cookbooks in between. bootsrtapping the server again and running the command worked